# modifying margins for one slide

Tags: beamer, margins

I need help for modifying the margins for only one slide in the `beamer` class

In other words, I need a local version of

```
\setbeamersize{text margin left=<size>,text margin right=<size>}
```

in here

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=5pt,text margin right=5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 85):

You can define a command for this using a `minipage` of the desired width inside a `\makebox` (using the optional argument you can change the default value of `3em` to any desired value):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\Wider[2][3em]{%
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+#1\relax}
  \raggedright#2
  \end{minipage}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\Wider{\lipsum[2]}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\Wider[4em]{\lipsum[2]}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option, would be to use a list, and this can be easily done using `adjustwidth` from the [`changepage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/changepage) package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5em}{-1.5em}
\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2em}{-2em}
\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The minipage approach does break `allowframebreaks`, while the changepage/adjustwidth approach works gorgeously, thanks.

Comment: What if I want to reduce left margin more than right margin? Thanks.

Comment: @YanKingYin I guess the second argument is for the right margin

Comment: What does it mean "use a list"? How the `adjustwidth` approach uses a list?

Answer (score 68):

Here is another solution using a `columns` environment with a single column:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{\dimexpr\paperwidth-10pt}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems the most simple option.

Comment: simple, and does the job perfectly

Answer (score 10):

Based on the **minipage** approach of the [**Answer of Gonzalo**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200172/36835) you can also introduce a new **frame environment** (*environ* package required) which is neat option if you'd like to use consistent wider frames for multiple slides or regularly want to change the textwidth of the whole slide.:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Rochester}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand{\halfmargin}{0.05\paperwidth}
\newcommand{\margin}{0.10\paperwidth}

\beamersetrightmargin{\margin}
\beamersetleftmargin{\margin}

\NewEnviron{wideframe}[1][]{%
\begin{frame}{#1}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\halfmargin-\halfmargin\relax}
\BODY
\end{minipage}}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\begin{wideframe}
\lipsum[2]
\end{wideframe}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: This would be nice but has some drawbacks: it breaks the heading format for some reason and it breaks frame options, e.g. `\begin{wideframe}[noframenumbering]{Abbreviations}` will create a slide with "noframenumbering" as title and "Abbreviations" as subtitle.

Comment: yep, didn't work for me either.

Comment: And it does not work with muti-page frames due to `allowframebreaks`.