# Negative indentation for beamer bibliography

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, indentation

As a part of my project, I redesigned the beamer default margins to **12 mm left margin** and **8 mm right margin**. But, I do not want this for bibliography, where the same left and right margins are preferred, ie **8mm left** and **8 mm right**.

Is there any way to do this ? Have look at the minimal working sample and the image attached with this.

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table},11pt]{beamer}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=12 mm, text margin right=8 mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{thebibliography}{plain}
\bibitem{} My reference one
\bibitem{} My reference two![enter image description here][1]
\bibitem{} All these references have 12 mm left margin, which I do not want.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160825/modifying-margins-for-one-slide

Comment: Yes, that thread is very much informative, and opened new windows of beamer customizations to me. Thank you Touhami for this !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick hack would be to redefine the `bibliography item` and add a negative `hspace` of your desired 4 mm to it.

The drawback: in case you have different types like books or online sources one would have to redefine all the different templates.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table},11pt]{beamer}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=12 mm, text margin right=8 mm}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\hspace{-0.4cm}\lower3pt\hbox{\pgfuseimage{beamericonarticle}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{thebibliography}{plain}
\bibitem{} My reference one
\bibitem{} My reference two![enter image description here][1]
\bibitem{} All these references have 12 mm left margin, which I do not want. Longer line
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```