# How to move table to left of frame in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I want to move table to left of frame so that enough space for other columns. 
I am using \longtable beacuse of lot of content also use of logtable added one extra slide.

[image]

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{lmodern,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
 \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\arraybackslash\RaggedRight}X} %%% for tiny table
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\arraybackslash\RaggedRight}p{#1}} %% for tiny table
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c,allowframebreaks]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt}  
    \tiny  %%  command to change the font size
    \begin{table}
        \hspace*{-\leftmargin}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \caption{Recent studies}
        \label{tableM} % table 2


    \begin{longtable}{p{1.4cm} l p{1cm}p{2cm}p{0.5cm}lp{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}}
            \hline

            Approach        &       Reference           &Domain             &Technique/strategies   &Hybrid method  & Sparsity  &   Cold-start& Scalability & Accuracy \\  \hline 

            Memory-based    &\cite{jhalani2016linear}   &Movie          &Linear regression      & \xmark                &    \xmark         &    \xmark         &    \xmark & \cmark \\             
            Memory-based    &\cite{kant2017enhanced}    &Movie          &Fuzzy bayesian             &  \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
            Memory-based    &\cite{mikeli2013multi}     &Movie          &Analytic hierarchy process (AHP) &\xmark  &  \xmark & \xmark  & \xmark & \cmark\\      
            Memory-based    &\cite{turk2019robustness}  &Movie          &Shilling Attack        &\xmark  &  \xmark & \xmark  & \xmark & \cmark\\
            Memory-based    &\cite{winarko2014improving}&Document       &Combination algorithm  &\xmark  &  \xmark & \xmark  & \xmark & \cmark\\        
 ...


 ....
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really have to present such a large table in a presentation?

Comment: You can change the margins with e.g. `\setbeamersize{text margin left=1mm,text margin right=1mm}` in your preamble, though this will affect all slides. Answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160825/modifying-margins-for-one-slide) provide ways of doing so for one slide.

Comment: @leandriis yes.. I have to show literature review in my presentation

Comment: @PatrickFerguson. no i want to change margin only in one slide. I tried adjustwidth from package changepage but it didn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first column of the table contains repetitive stuff that might as well be placed in a sub-row header. Having 1 column less to deal with hugely beneficial as it lets you change the relative font size from `\tiny` to `\scriptsize`.

I would also allow line breaks in the final five columns.

And whatever else you do, don't wrap a `longtable` inside a `table`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,longtable}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight}X} 
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} 
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} 

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Recent studies in MCRS}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}  % default: 6pt
\scriptsize  
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.333} % '1.50' seems excessive

\begin{longtable}{@{} P{2cm} l P{2cm} C{9mm} *{4}{C{8mm}} @{}}
% header and footer settings
\toprule
Reference & Domain & Technique\slash strategies 
& Hybrid method & Sparsity & Cold-start & Scalability & Accuracy \\  
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

% body of longtable
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{A. Memory-based approaches}\\
\cite{jhalani2016linear}   &Movie    &Linear regression      &\xmark &\xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \cmark \\             
\cite{kant2017enhanced}    &Movie    &Fuzzy Bayesian         &\xmark &\xmark & \xmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
\cite{mikeli2013multi}     &Movie    &Analytic hierarchy process (AHP) &\xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \cmark\\      
\cite{turk2019robustness}  &Movie    &Shilling Attack        &\xmark &\xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \cmark\\
\cite{winarko2014improving}&Document &Combination algorithm  &\xmark &\xmark & \xmark & \xmark & \cmark\\        
\dots & \dots & \dots \\
\end{longtable}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```