# Adding more space between rows in a tabular environment which has matrices

Tags: tables, spacing, matrices

I am getting this on beamer using `tabular`:

[image]

As you can see, the matrices are too close to the middle line, and I would like to separate these matrices a little from it. Adding `\\ \\ \hline \\` between the last cell of the first row and  the first cell of the second row yields

[image]

I do consider this to be be too much space between the rows and the middle line. If I try to add `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` before the `tabular` environment (as it is recommended [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26692/150120)), it yields

[image]

and suddenly all matrices stretch big as well. I think this happens because the variable `\arraystretch` applies globally to both `tabular` and `pmatrix`. With the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` before the `\begin{tabular}`, I tried to reredefine this variable back to `1` before each `\begin{pmatrix}` and it neither worked.

Here's a MWE, with the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` before the `tabular` environment, which gives the last image:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} % This deletes the index on top of each slide
\usefonttheme{default}

\newcommand\wider[2][3em]{%
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+#1\relax}
  \raggedright#2
  \end{minipage}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \wider[3em]{\small
    \bgroup\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    \begin{tabular}{c|lll}
            \begin{minipage}{35pt}
            \centering base de $\mathsf{su}(2)$
            \end{minipage} &
            $E_{1}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
            i & 0 \\
            0 & -i
            \end{pmatrix}$ , &
            $E_{2}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
            0 & i \\
            i & 0
            \end{pmatrix}$ , &
            $E_{3}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
            0 & -1 \\
            1 & 0
            \end{pmatrix}.$
        \\\hline
            \begin{minipage}{35pt}
            \centering base de $\mathsf{so}(3)$
            \end{minipage} &
            $F_1=\begin{pmatrix}
            0&0&0\\
            0&0&-1\\
            0&1&0
            \end{pmatrix},$ &
            $F_2=\begin{pmatrix}
            0&0&1\\
            0&0&0\\
            -1&0&0
            \end{pmatrix},$ &
            $F_3=\begin{pmatrix}
            0&-1&0\\
            1&0&0\\
            0&0&0
            \end{pmatrix}.$
    \end{tabular}
    \egroup
    }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

where I am using the `\wider` macro defined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160827/150120) to decrease lateral margins on the slide.

I would like to get then something like in the second image but with less space between the rows and the middle line. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You may liked:

[image]

It is produced with MWE, which use the `tabularray` package and `\small` font size in matrices. Code is simple and quite short:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{array,tabularray}
\NewColumnType{C}{>{\small $}X<{$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c,m,4em] | C C C },
             colsep=3pt,
             rowsep=3pt,
             }
base de $su(2)$
    &   E_{1}=\frac{1}{2}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            i & 0 \\
            0 & -i
            \end{pmatrix}, 
        &   E_{2}=\frac{1}{2}
            \begin{pmatrix}
            0 & i \\
            i & 0
            \end{pmatrix}, 
        &   E_{3}=\frac{1}{2}
            \begin{pmatrix}
            0 & -1 \\
            1 & 0
            \end{pmatrix}.      \\  
    \hline
base de $so(3)$
    &   F_1=\begin{pmatrix}
            0&0&0\\
            0&0&-1\\
            0&1&0
            \end{pmatrix},
    &   F_2=\begin{pmatrix}
            0&0&1\\
            0&0&0\\
            -1&0&0
            \end{pmatrix},
    &   F_3=\begin{pmatrix}
            0&-1&0\\
            1&0&0\\
            0&0&0
            \end{pmatrix}.
    \end{tblr}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and its key `cell-space-limits`.

```
\documentclass[spanish]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\usefonttheme{default}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand\wider[2][3em]{%
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+#1\relax}
  \raggedright#2
  \end{minipage}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \wider[3em]{\small
    \bgroup\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c|lll}[cell-space-limits=5pt]
            \begin{minipage}{35pt}
            \centering base de $\mathsf{su}(2)$
            \end{minipage} &
            $E_{1}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
            i & 0 \\
            0 & -i
            \end{pmatrix}$ , &
            $E_{2}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
            0 & i \\
            i & 0
            \end{pmatrix}$ , &
            $E_{3}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
            0 & -1 \\
            1 & 0
            \end{pmatrix}.$
        \\\hline
            \begin{minipage}{35pt}
            \centering base de $\mathsf{so}(3)$
            \end{minipage} &
            $F_1=\begin{pmatrix}
            0&0&0\\
            0&0&-1\\
            0&1&0
            \end{pmatrix},$ &
            $F_2=\begin{pmatrix}
            0&0&1\\
            0&0&0\\
            -1&0&0
            \end{pmatrix},$ &
            $F_3=\begin{pmatrix}
            0&-1&0\\
            1&0&0\\
            0&0&0
            \end{pmatrix}.$
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \egroup
    }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I have just found a solution with the package `cellspace`. Since I cannot find an analogous solution on other questions here on TSE, I am posting the answer.

To add space between a the content of a cell and a `\hline`, the `cellspace` package requires you to add `S` before the `c`, `l` or `c` position parameter of `tabular` (as it is explained on its documentation), so for instance

```
\begin{tabular}{l l l p{3cm}}
```

has to be changed into

```
\begin{tabular}{Sl Sl Sl Sp{3cm}}
```

For extra space in the cells, the parameters `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit` may be modified with `\setlength`. In my particular case, I get
[image]
with the code

```
\documentclass[spanish]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} % This deletes the index on top of each slide
\usefonttheme{default}
\usepackage{cellspace}

\newcommand\wider[2][3em]{%
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+#1\relax}
  \raggedright#2
  \end{minipage}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \wider[3em]{\small
    \bgroup\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{5pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{Sc | Sl Sl Sl}
            \begin{minipage}{35pt}
            \centering base de $\mathsf{su}(2)$
            \end{minipage} &
            $E_{1}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
            i & 0 \\
            0 & -i
            \end{pmatrix}$ , &
            $E_{2}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
            0 & i \\
            i & 0
            \end{pmatrix}$ , &
            $E_{3}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
            0 & -1 \\
            1 & 0
            \end{pmatrix}.$
        \\\hline
            \begin{minipage}{35pt}
            \centering base de $\mathsf{so}(3)$
            \end{minipage} &
            $F_1=\begin{pmatrix}
            0&0&0\\
            0&0&-1\\
            0&1&0
            \end{pmatrix},$ &
            $F_2=\begin{pmatrix}
            0&0&1\\
            0&0&0\\
            -1&0&0
            \end{pmatrix},$ &
            $F_3=\begin{pmatrix}
            0&-1&0\\
            1&0&0\\
            0&0&0
            \end{pmatrix}.$
    \end{tabular}
    \egroup
    }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```